# How to See Hidden Layers of PSD File in Preview of Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, adobe-photoshop, preview

I am using Preview in Mac OS X 10.5.8 which is able to open .psd files (Photoshop documents). I couldn't find an option for enable & disable view of some layers.

My client has sent me a .psd file through mail and has put some layers as hidden. Is it possible to view hidden layers or change what layers are visible in Preview?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preview has very limited support for Photoshop documents (beyond viewing them) and can not change what layers are hidden and what layers are not in a Photoshop file.

However, there are different programs (image editors) you can use to view the Photoshop file if you don't own Photoshop:

1. [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) (Free and Open Source)
2. [Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/) (Not free but much nicer to use)

Answer (score 2):

GIMP is a good idea. You could also download a trial of some version of Photoshop (CS4 or elements) if you don't plan to make a habit of working with layered PSDs. I suggest this because I don't like GIMP, but it will do what you want.